# Regex to check date format M/d/yy h:mm tt

Tags: regex

Can someone help me find the regular expression to detect the date format M/d/yy h:mm tt.

i.e: 4/3/19 5:27 AM   but also 12/31/19 11:59 PM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With group 1 matching date and group 2 matching hour

Run the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/z1qr8j/1) here

```
([0-9]+\/[0-9]+\/[0-9]+)\s([0-9]+:[0-9]+\s(?:A|P)M+)
```

If you want to keep the matching 1 and 2 but only accept valid dates.

Run the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/ke3um3/4) here

```
((?:[1-9]|1[012])\/(?:[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/\d{2})\s((?:[0-1]?\d|2[0-3]):(?:(?:[0-5]?\d))\s(?:A|P)M)
```

Comment: This one works fine but is there a way to check if the days and months are valid (month is always between 1-12; days always between 1 -31)

Comment: The  answer proposed by @AlwaysSunny was working as well and only catching the days in range [0;31], months in range [0;12] and hour in range [0;24]. But you still might catch a "30/02/19".

Comment: His regex is fine but only yours worked on Oracle DB.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about your language but it should work on most of the programming language. Let's try like this way-

```
(0?[1-9]|1[012])\/(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/\d{2} ([0-1]?\d|2[0-3])(?::([0-5]?\d)) (A|P)M
```

**SEE:** https://regex101.com/r/fsp3FS/27

Comment: This didn't work on Oracle DB. I had to take off the ?::